# Solving Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 -\sin(x+y)/(\sin y \cos x)$ by separating variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial value is $y(\frac{\pi}{4})$.

I got to $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1 - \frac{\sin(x) \cos(y) + \sin(y) \cos(x)}{\sin(y)\cos(x)}$ by using the $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \sin(y) \cos(x)$ property. However, I don't know what to do next in order to solve.

Comment: Did you try simplifying?

Comment: Try putting the 1 into the fraction and see what happens

Answer (score 6):

Note that:$$1-\frac { \sin x \cos y+\sin y \cos x }{ \sin y \cos x } =1-\left( \frac { \sin x \cos y }{ \sin y \cos x } +\frac { \sin y \cos x }{ \sin y\cos x }  \right) =1-\tan { x } \cot { y } -1=-\tan { x } \cot { y } \\ \\ $$
 so your actually equation is :

> $$\frac { dy }{ dx } =-\tan { x } \cot { y }  $$

$y=\pm \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $ is a solution.Other solutions we can find by solving this equation as below.

$$\int { \frac { dy }{ \cot { y }  }  } =-\int { \tan { x } dx\quad \Rightarrow  } \int { \frac { \sin { y }  }{ \cos { y }  } dy=-\int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos { x }  } dx\quad \Rightarrow  } -\int { \frac { d\cos { y }  }{ \cos { y }  }  }  } =\int { \frac { d\cos { x }  }{ \cos { x }  }  } \Rightarrow -\ln { \left| \cos { y }  \right| =\ln { C\left| \cos { x }  \right|  }  } \\ \ln { \left| \frac { 1 }{ \cos { y }  }  \right| =\ln { C\left| \cos { x }  \right|  }  } \Rightarrow $$
so the answer is :

> $$\left| \cos { x } \cos { y }  \right| =C\quad and\quad y=\pm \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $$

Comment: I believe you may be missing a $(-)$ sign

Comment: @Did,thanks for observation,i edited

Comment: This can be given explicitly as $y=\arccos(C\sec x)$, i.e. you can drop the absolute value signs.

Comment: @WillFisher,good point thanks)